# need help in jolt transformation where a filed is a json string instead of pure json

Tags: json, json.net, jolt

```
{
  "clientid": "129710",
  "delivery_status": [
    {
      "x-apiheader": "{\"txnid\":\"129710-122-2079719-0-230502181123\",\"senttime\":\"2023-05-02 18:11:23\",\"mobile\":\"9488702697\",\"linkId\":956}"
    },
    {
      "x-apiheader": "{\"txnid\":\"9710-122-2079719-0-230502181123\",\"senttime\":\"2023-05-02 18:11:23\",\"mobile\":\"9488702697\",\"linkId\":956}"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is my input JSON ,here x-apiheader under  delivery_status is a JSOn string instead of a proper JSON map.

I would like the output to be something like this

```
[
{"txnId":"129710-122-2079719-0-230502181123"},
{"txnId":"9710-122-2079719-0-230502181123"}
]
```

I have tried with a few specs but they are not working as they all expect a JSON map instead of a Json String. Any guidance would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **modify** and **shift** specs consecutively such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "delivery_status": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=split(\",@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "delivery_status": {
        "*": {
          "@(0,x-apiheader[3])": "[#2].@(1,x-apiheader[1])"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** one the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]